# Query not executing after changes in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
if(empty($Errormessage))
            {
                    if(move_uploaded_file($File_Tmp,"product_images/".$File_Name))
                    {
                        //To Rename the uploaded file
                        $Random=rand()*1200;
                        $File_New_Name=$Random.".".$File_Extension;
                        rename("product_images/".$File_Name,"product_images/".$File_New_Name);  
                        $Date_Added=date("d-m-Y");
                        $Query="INSERT INTO products (pro_id,product_name,price,details,product_picture,date_added,last_edited,cat_id) VALUES ('','$Product_Name','$Product_Price','$Product_Details','$File_New_Name','$Date_Added','','$Category')";
                        $Result=mysql_query($Query);
                    if($Result)
                        {
                            header ("location: addsuccess.php");
                        }

                    }
            }
```

//Category

```
<td><select name="category" size="1" id="select">
      <option value="Null">Select Category</option>
      <?php
      $Select=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category");
      while ($Row=mysql_fetch_array($Select))
      { 
            $Cat_Id=$Row['cat_id'];
            $Category_Name=$Row['category_name'];
      ?>
        <option value="$Cat_Id"><?php echo $Category_Name; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select></td>
```

//validation

```
if($Category=="Null")
        {
            $Errormessage[]="Category should be selected";
        }
```

cat_id is a column as FK in my products table... and also cat_id is a primary key in category table... since i made this cat_id a FK actually i copy pasted the syntax of alter table add column fk etc etc... it is nt letting my save my records ... i tried it directly on php my admin by passing dummy values .. it is working.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I m nt getting any error ... it is saving the picture in my folder ..and page is refreshed just.... with no errors

Comment: Your code tells that $Errormessage has to be empty and file has to uploaded correctly. What is the value of $Errormessage. Is it empty? Does the code actually go into the if-statement where uploading begins?

Comment: yes error msg is an array of validation errors

Comment: <?php
function errors($Errormessage){
$showError = null;
if (isset($Errormessage)){
$i = 0;
while ($i < count($Errormessage)){
$showError.= '<div class="msg-error">'.$Errormessage[$i].'</div>';
$i ++;
}
return $showError;
}
}
?>

Comment: it is saving file means the move_uploaded_file is working fine... but something is wrong after it

Comment: Doesn't the product go into the database you mean? if ($Result) tells it to redirect to addsuccess.php so it should be refreshed if query worked. Have you tried to do the query in phpMyAdmin (or similar) ?

Comment: LET ME TRY IT DIRCETLY N PHPMYADMIN

Comment: #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mystore`.`products`, CONSTRAINT `products_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cat_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`cat_id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Comment: There you have it then :-) $Category has to be set to correct ID. Also look at my answer when inserting products.

Comment: ITS NOT WORKING :S seems there is some prob in my FK column coz i just copy pasted the syntax .... i dnt knw how to make it proper.... :S can u please tell me how can i add a column cat_id in my products table and make it a FK reference category(cat_id)

Comment: Can you manually insert in phpMyAdmin (not SQL) the product you intend to with the category you intend to?

Comment: INSERT INTO products (pro_id,product_name,price,details,product_picture,date_added,last_edited,cat_id) VALUES ('','Deskt','1000','blah','bla','bla','bla','1') it worked :S

Comment: i run above query directly in mysql and it saved the data :S

Comment: Yes of course, but that didn't solve the actual problem. What is the value of $Category? Look at my updated answer. I guess $Category is of type INT in the db-column.

Comment: Nik saying that i cannot use $Category to insert cat_id because it is connected to another table.. what does that mean... then what is the purpose of FK ...actually $Category is a value of select list... and my select list is dynamic... it is getting values from my category table

Comment: yes it is int ? i have to save only id of categry ..thats why i put it int ??

Comment: INT is fine, but what's the value of $Category?

Comment: value is $category

td><select name="category" size="1" id="select">
      <option value="Null">Select Category</option>
      <?php
   $Select=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category");
   while ($Row=mysql_fetch_array($Select))
   { 
     $Cat_Id=$Row['cat_id'];
   $Category_Name=$Row['category_name'];
   ?>
        <option value="$Cat_Id"><?php echo $Category_Name; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select></td>

Comment: Please insert the code inside your question instead (it's hard to read in comment). Edit your question and do the pasting :-)

Comment: wait let me update all my code

Comment: Where is the actual code for RETRIEVING the $Category? Like $Category = $_POST['category'] ?

Comment: $Category=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);

Comment: This is not correct way of doing it. Escaping in this way would probably return NULL. Look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
$Query="INSERT INTO products (pro_id, product_name,price,details,product_picture,date_added,last_edited,cat_id) VALUES (NULL,'$Product_Name','$Product_Price','$Product_Details','$File_New_Name','$Date_Added','',$Category)";
```

NULL instead of '' might solve your issue. Also $Category is without **apostrophes** now because db-column cat_id is a number and not a string. (Numbers should not be handled with apostrophes).

```
$Category=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
```

(You're trying to escape a **string**, but $_POST['category'] is a **number**), so it's no the correct way of doing it).

It should be something like:

```
if (isset($_POST['category'])) {
   $Category = $_POST['category'];
}
else {
   $Category = 0;
}
```

Also change:

```
  ?>
    <option value="$Cat_Id"><?php echo $Category_Name; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
```

TO

```
  ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $Cat_Id;?>"><?php echo $Category_Name; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
```

It's also strongly recommended to use PDO or Mysqli. It will save a lot of time and problems for the future. mysql-functions like mysql_query is deprecated and is going to be removed in future releases of php.

Comment: wait let me try.... but i dont think it will wrk :S i tried removing $category from my query it stil ldint work...let me check this one

Comment: What is the output of $Category here? (add echo $Category; on the last line)

Comment: :( no it just refreshing the page itself

Comment: What is the output of $Category?

Comment: $Cat_Id  what is thatttttttttttt :s i echoed out $category and it said $Cat_ID

Comment: That explains it. $Category='$Cat_ID'. You haven't done the assignment of $Cat_ID correctly in the html-part... I've updated. Take a look.

Comment: yeahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh :D:D:D:D

Comment: thank you so muchhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh :D but i m confused when i deleted $category from my query why didn't it worked then ?

Comment: You're welcome :-) Deleting $category from your query doesn't delete the foreign key in the database. Probably that's why (you HAD to have a cat_id assignment in query with rules coming from db).

Comment: ohhh i see .... thanks :D i was about to thrw my laptop in a moment :D hehe u saved my life (Y)

Answer (score 0):

So that's the error. There is mistake on your cat_id reference. Check the db constraints. $Category is INSERTED mistakenly. E.g. If cat_id is connected with an other table, you cannot insert it with $Category.

Comment: I called cateogry id and name frm category table in a drp down list.... value=$cat_id ...  and now i used $_Post['categry']=$Category... i want to save and id of category in the products table ....

Comment: First check your query to be sure that is the cat_id fault. That's a quick troubleshooting. Detach the cat_id and $Category and run the script. If it the script is inserted correctly, you need to make a separate insert category query before the $Query and then use  $Category=mysql_insert_id() to pass the id to the $Query.

Comment: i tried removing cat_id and $category still din't work.. it is runing till move uploaded file